# C++ coin toss program

Tags: c++

I tried to make a C++ program to calculate how many coin tosses of the same type I've gotten in a row, but the results are strange. I tried to toss it 1,000,000 times and I haven't gotten more "in a row tosses of the same type" than 15. I tested it on smaller number of tosses (5-20) and it seemed to be working correctly except I also haven't gotten more than 15 of the same type in a row.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

#define LOOP 1000000//how many times do I toss a coin

int main()
{
int maxTails = 0, maxHeads = 0, currentTails = 0, currentHeads = 0, totalHeads = 0, totalTails = 0;

int totalMax = 0;//highest amount of "in a row" out of all iterations

bool heads = false;//last toss

srand(time(0));

for (int x = 0; x < 100; ++x) {//this is to increase the amount of how many times I want to toss a coin LOOP times
    for (int i = 0; i < LOOP; ++i)//tosses a coin LOOP times
    {
        if (rand() % 2 == 0)// heads
        {
            if (heads == false)//if last toss was tails I check if the "in a row" for it was more than the current maximum
            {
                if (currentTails > maxTails) maxTails = currentTails;
                currentTails = 0;
                currentHeads = 0;
                heads = true;
            }
            currentHeads++;
            totalHeads++;
            if (currentHeads > maxHeads) maxHeads = currentHeads;
        }
        else//tails
        {
            if (heads == true)
            {
                if (currentHeads > maxHeads) maxHeads = currentHeads;
                currentHeads = 0;
                currentTails = 0;
                heads = false;
            }
            currentTails++;
            totalTails++;
            if (currentTails > maxTails) maxTails = currentTails;
        }
    }

    if (maxTails > totalMax) totalMax = maxTails;//totalMax is the maximum "in a row" of either tails or heads
    if (maxHeads > totalMax) totalMax = maxHeads;

    std::cout << "Throws: " << LOOP << ", Total heads: " << totalHeads << ", Total tails: " << totalTails << ", Maximum heads: " << maxHeads << ", Maximum tails: " << maxTails << std::endl;//writes all the info
    //std::cout << "Iteration: " << x + 1 << ", Max: " << totalMax << std::endl;
    maxTails = maxHeads = currentHeads = currentTails = totalHeads = totalTails = 0;
}
std::cout << "Max: " << totalMax << std::endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

I've read on the internet, that there is a ~38% chance of getting 20 heads in a row if you toss a coin 1,000,000 times but my program works differently. Is there a problem in my code or is it maybe some problem with the rand() function?

Comment: `srand(time(Null));`

Comment: "my program works differently": In what way(s)?

Comment: Something that has a 38% chance of happening didn't happen; what is the question?

Comment: @FirstStep relevant username ;)

Comment: Make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then edit the question to replace the current code with that. Then, edit the rest of your question to say what you expect to happen, what is happening instead, and how you've tried to fix it already. In addition, change your title to a succinct description of your problem.

Comment: I get more than 20 here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eaa98e4703a79f91

Comment: I'm amazed that rand() is that good! There's no way it will have the correct statistical properties for it to be appropriate for this application. You could try the new mersenne twister generator, but I'm not convinced it would pass this statistical test. Methinks your only option would be to use special hardware or a sequence generated from something like that (you can download them).

Comment: @Bath d* right. Exactly what I was thinking. Related info: http://www-cdf.fnal.gov/physics/statistics/notes/cdf6850_badrand.pdf

Comment: [Visual Studio](http://rextester.com/TPSV6339)'s `rand` seems particularly bad.

Comment: If `currentHeads` == `maxHeads` == `totalHeads` && `currentTails` == `maxTails` == `totalTails`, why have **three** sets of variables tracking the same count? Are you just trying to flip a coin? Or track the max times heads/tails appears in a row? What result is desired?

Comment: @FirstStep Looks like your answer is very close to what the OP is possibly looking for.

Comment: @NonCrea right? I was like why the h* this guy is duplicating everything to get his result

Answer (score 1):

Read @BathSheba comment. It is just not accurate to expect different output than what you are getting now.

For the sake of simplicity so readers can debug if desired, this is a working version of your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

#define LOOP 1000000 //how many times do I toss a coin

int main()
{
    int maxTails = 0;
    int maxHeads = 0;
    int currentTotalTails = 0; 
    int currentTotalHeads = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < LOOP; ++i) //tosses a coin LOOP times
    {
        if (rand() % 2 == 0)// heads
        {
            currentTotalHeads++;
            currentTotalTails = 0;

            if (currentTotalHeads > maxHeads)
                maxHeads = currentTotalHeads;

        }
        else // tails
        {
            currentTotalTails++;
            currentTotalHeads = 0;

            if (currentTotalTails > maxTails)
                maxTails = currentTotalTails;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Max Heads in a row: " << maxHeads << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Max Tails in a row: " << maxTails << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: out of interest, what happens if you switch to  mersenne twister?

Comment: The problem is that the resulting number ( totalMax ) is not bigger than 15 even though after hundreds of tries there is a big chance of it being higher.
FirstStep thank you for simplifying the code, but it has given me the same results ( totalMax is not over 15 ). It seems to be the problem that Bathsheba mentioned - the Visual Studio rand() function. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: @Bath I really want to know but I don't know anything about the mersenne twister

Comment: @warozell take a read of [std::uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).  Much better, and still standard-supported, random number generator.

Comment: It's part of he c++11 standard library. I'd try myself but it ain't much fun using them via an iPhone on a choo choo.

Comment: But really I think you need a generator that is truly Markov to solve this problem. And that's only available afaik via special hardware boards that have radioactive decay isotopes etc on them.

Comment: BathSheba interesting.. Why @NathanOliver got better results? Maybe this is why or it does not matter and it is not the case?

Comment: Hacking the above to do Twister I get... Right hand red! But seriously folks, usually around 20, but I've spiked into the 30s.

Comment: @FirstStep Implementations are allowed to implement `rand` however they want.  Apparently gcc made a more random generator than MSVS.

Comment: @Nathan I see.. But why in your opinion, here it is `15` and not something else?

Comment: @FirstStep Most likely the generator has a small enough period where you start repeating the sequence before you reach the end of the million cases.  If that happens then the results will always be the same like what the OP observed.

Comment: @Nathan so if we do something equivalent to `Thread.Sleep(x++)` on every iteration where `x` starts from 0, we should be able to get the exact answer?

Comment: @FirstStep Sorry but I don't get the question.  My theory of what is happening is `rand` has a fixed period of values it can produce before it starts the sequence all over again(at least in the OP's implementation).  If that period is smaller then then the number of times you call `rand` then each time you run you will get the same values since you wind back up where you started.  This is why the OP always gets 15, even though the seed changes, each "run" covers all values of `rand` so you will always get the same results. at least that is how I think it works.  I have known to be wrong.

Comment: @nathanoliver: I think you are correct here. I'm still amazed that a linear congruential gerenator can draw 15 odd numbers in a row.

Comment: @Bathsheba It didn't(most likely).  The OP is using `(rand() % 2 == 0)` so all it had to do was pick 15 odd or even numbers in a row.

Comment: That's kinda what I meant. I'm still amazed. Must be a curious interaction between the multiplier, constant, and the modulus. One to examine on a rainy day.

Comment: Oh oops, misread your comment.  Definitely rainy day material.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem with your random number generation.  Since all random number generators work using the clock and the amount of time that has passed since it was seeded, if the execution of your code takes about the same amount of time each loop, then patterns will emerge.  This would explain why it only comes up as 15.  I had made a rock paper scissors game in my intro class that I could win consistently at a 90% rate (not a very fair game).

Try varying your control flow.  Have a random number generator that will control how many iterations take place

```
loopCnt = 0;
while(loopCnt < LOOP)
{
    nextLoops = rand() % (LOOP - loopCnt);
    for(int i = 0; i < nextLoops; ++i)
    {
        // COUNT IN A ROW.
        ++loopCnt;
    }
}
```

That should vary up your flow that patterns won't emerge.

Comment: You might want to consider a Bays-Durham shuffle. Your technique is on the road to that. But I don't think that would be good enough. Sadly I think your method knackers the generator!

Comment: Moral of the story is random numbers aren't random.